# Is it "Pythonic" to type check function arguments?

Tags: python, strong-typing, duck-typing

Coming from C/C++ background I have always been little set back by the Python's lack of strong type checking. Therefore it always led me to writing code of this style:

```
def function (this_should_be_list, this_should_be_int):

    isFristArgList = isinstance(this_should_be_list,list)
    if not isFristArgList:
        raise Exception("The first argument should be a list!")

    isSecondArgInt = isinstance(this_should_be_int,int)
    if not IsSecondArgInt:
        raise Exception ("The second argument should be an int!")

    ....
    ....
    ....

    return
```

which leads to slightly more convoluted and bloated code which is opposite to, in my understanding to, "Pythonic philosophy" of writing as clear code as it possible. In opposition to this  dynamic checking approach, one may say that without it, *function* will also fail and raise some exception so it doesn't make really any difference, but I would argue that it is really hard to predict (especially within bigger codebase with multiple nested calls) whether somewhere there is some corner case bug that will make out *function* execute correct on "surface" but incorrectly from what we intended it to do.

So my question is, how should I approach this in Python?
Am I just biased towards strongly typed "style" due to my previous experience with C/C++, and should just embrace the duck typed nature of Python?
Or maybe, is there some more elegant way to type check in Python?

Comment: first you can use type hinting instead. Then there's no rule: if you notice that people are misusing your API or the error messages are cryptic when they do, then you can start protecting your API. Else let duck typing act

Comment: While python doesn't support strong type checking it has supported type hints for a while, at least 3.5 and beyond.  see [Support for type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) in the docs.

Comment: Use mypy!  http://mypy-lang.org/

Answer (score 2):

Use type annotations and [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/).  This gives you all the benefits of static type checking, and does not generally require significant changes to the way you write Python code, other than adding annotations to function declarations.

```
# Annotate your parameters like this:
def function(this_should_be_list: list, this_should_be_int: int):
    pass


# Then when you run mypy on your code, it tells you when types don't match:
function([1, 2, 3], 10)  
function(10, "foo")   # error: Argument 1 to "function" has incompatible type "int"; expected "List[Any]"   
                      # error: Argument 2 to "function" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int"
```

Just run `mypy` as part of your regular testing strategy, similar to how you'd verify that C++ code passes compile-time checks.  If you do that, it's not generally necessary to do runtime checks, any more than you would in C++ code.

Comment: Thanks for answer, mypy looks like a really useful tool!

Comment: Run time checks can still be valid on user accessed functions.  Especially when they prevent an error appearing in an unclear way or later in the code.

Answer (score -2):

It can be done in a Pythonic way if necessary, but you need to establish if the `type` is what really matters.  E.g., does the first variable **have** to be a *list*, or does it need to be an iterable?  Does the 2nd **have** to be an *int*, or does it need to have a non-zero fractional part?

Assuming the answers to both questions is "yes", I would modify your code to:

```py
def function (this_should_be_list, this_should_be_int):

    if not hasattr(this_should_be_list, '__iter__'):
        raise Exception("The first argument should be an iterable!")

    if this_should_be_int%1 != 0:
        raise Exception ("The second argument should be integer!")

    ....
    ....
    ....

    return
```